# PHP Long formula calculations gives wrong answers?

Tags: php, math, coordinates

So my problem is this. I have a formula (see picture), according to which I'm supposed to calculate some coordinates, given in output field.

[image]

I made my formulas in php, but it returns the wrong results.

Formula :

```
    $inpx =(string)3484481.0943; //input X
    $inpy =(string)3144325.1033;//input Y
    $inpz =(string)4305103.1740;//input Z

    $dx=-2.0796; //delta X
    $dy=-0.3484; //delta Y
    $dz=1.7009;  //delta Z
    $rx=(string)(0.05465/3600)*(string)(M_PI/180);  
    $ry=(string)(-0.06718/3600)*(string)(M_PI/180);
    $rz=(string)(0.06143/3600)*(string)(M_PI/180);
    $k=(string)0.0181/(string)pow(10,6);
    $n=1+$k;

    $X84=$n*$inpx-$rz*$n*$inpy+$ry*$n*$inpz+$dx;
    $Y84=$rz*$n*$inpx+$n*$inpy-$rx*$n*$inpz+$dy;
    $Z84=-$ry*$n*$inpx+$rx*$n*$inpy+$n*$inpz+$dz;

    $X84 = round($X84,4);
    $Y84 = round($Y84,4);
    $Z84 = round($Z84,4);
```

The results that I'm supposed to get

> ```
>   $X84 = 3484481.4163;
>   $Y84 = 3144324.9149;
>   $Z84 = 4305102.9848;
> ```

The results that I get

> ```
>   $X84 = 3484476.7392;
>   $Y84 = 3144324.7089;
>   $Z84 = 4305106.9208;
> ```

Would be appreciated if someone could find what I have wrong in my formula, because I have been messing with it for a few days now.

Comment: `(string)` should be removed. `$k = 0.0181E-6;` or `0.0181 * 1E-6`.

Comment: removing (string) had no effect, it still returned the same answers

Comment: I initially thought this had to do with double/single precision, but I reproduced this in Java with explicit double-precision numbers and got the same answers as you.

Comment: And I just redid it using `float`s instead of `double`s everywhere, and got `X84 = 3484476.5, Y84 = 3144324.5, Z84 = 4305106.5`. That's not as far off as the difference between your answers and the 'gold standard' answers you were given. I suspect your calculation's just not exactly doing what you expect it to. Break it into pieces and see if you can make the individual pieces correct, then put the pieces together.

Comment: I checked with floats and got the same answer as you did,  in as3 as well , but got the same results. The people who I'm making this for checked my code and formulas from top to bottom and it was all correct, but the answers are still returned wrong.

Comment: I did break it, into veeery little pieces, and each and every one of the components is correct, but its not doing the last equation for some god damn reason

Comment: You're passing in a lot of literal numbers in the first ten lines or so... you're sure each and every last digit is correct? No transpositions?

Comment: Otherwise I just don't know. Your matrix multiplication looks right. And I can't find any unexpected order-of-operations weirdness.

Comment: These calculators are supposed to be on a website, the variables in input field are supposed to be written in by users and thus calculating. the digits i'm giving here are sample digits given by client for testing which was calculated by their ready calculator.

Comment: Sorry, I tried but I got nothin' else. Good luck solving the problem. :-)

Comment: What is also strange is, if you add `echo "{$n} * {$inpx} - {$rz} * {$n} * {$inpy} + {$ry} * {$n} * {$inpz} + {$dx} = {$X84}` after your `$X84...` line, and then take what is output and put into another online calc (even those claiming to be super precise), you still get the same output.

Comment: Using Excel I get the following results $X84=3484477.6761, $Y84=3144325.6520, $Z84=4305107.8429. Nobody has asked yet about the expected values of $X84 = 3484481.4163,  $Y84 = 3144324.9149, $Z84 = 4305102.9848 and how these were obtained. Could there have been an error in obtaining these values?

Comment: I am not a math expert but i gave it a shot to try come closer to the wanted result.i took ony the first result `$X84 = round($X84,4);` and did `$X84=$n*$inpx-$rz*$n*($inpy+$ry*$n*$inpz+$dx);` return: 3484480.2209 . then i did some researching and found that it could be a [CPU](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) issue.

Comment: I think unless the OP comes back to advise how the expected results were obtained, there isn't much more we can do....

Comment: They were received by a already made calculator that the client is using, unfortunatelly we cant "open up and see" how the calculator is working, but it is used by the national Tourism agency of my country so i don't think it gives the wrong results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**
After further consideration, I believe you have an error with the positive and negative sign on your inputed rv values.

```
$inpx =(float)3484481.0943; //input X
$inpy =(float)3144325.1033;//input Y
$inpz =(float)4305103.1740;//input Z

$dx=-2.0796; //delta X
$dy=-0.3484; //delta Y
$dz=1.7009;  //delta Z
```

Before:

```
$rx=(float)(0.05465/3600)*(float)(M_PI/180);  
$ry=(float)(-0.06718/3600)*(float)(M_PI/180);
$rz=(float)(0.06143/3600)*(float)(M_PI/180);
```

After and resulting in the correct results:

```
$rx=(float)(-0.05465/3600)*(float)(M_PI/180);  
$ry=(float)(0.06718/3600)*(float)(M_PI/180);
$rz=(float)(-0.06143/3600)*(float)(M_PI/180);
```

Just by changing the positive and negative sign on all three rv values, I receive the expected results.

```
$k=(float)0.0181/(float)pow(10,6);
$n=1+$k;
```

For clarityI have also added some parentheses to the following function.

```
$X84=($inpx*$n)+(-$rz*$inpy*$n)+($ry*$inpz*$n)+$dx;
$Y84=($rz*$n*$inpx)+($n*$inpy)+(-$rx*$n*$inpz)+$dy;
$Z84=(-$ry*$n*$inpx)+($rx*$n*$inpy)+($n*$inpz)+$dz;

$X84 = round($X84,4);
$Y84 = round($Y84,4);
$Z84 = round($Z84,4);

print_r($X84); //3484481.4164 
print_r($Y84); //3144324.9147
print_r($Z84); //4305102.9848
```

Hope this helps solving your problem!

Comment: Updated old solution after a nights thought about it!

Comment: yw, happy to hear it helped.